# How to restrict access to Bluemix Scalable group container to public?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have created a scalable group container with the latest image, which is created by docker file. I have added a domain name and used an SSL certificate with it. However, I am looking to restrict this domain access to public. I would like to allow access to a specific IP range only.

Is there any approach I can use to achieve this? The client asked to allow this domain URL access within their FW network only.

Many Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't any available service/configuration to restrict access to container/containers group in the IBM Containers service on Bluemix.

The only options coming to my mind could be:

- filtering directly on each of your group's nodes, using iptables or the specific service configuration
- have a 'filter' container (or also an application on runtime) filtering the connections according to the source IP address, for example using a proxy like varnish or ha_proxy on a container it will be pretty simple